# Roslyn Restore.cmd fails with "Could not find a part of the path"

Tags: installation, roslyn

In the instructions for working with Roslyn on a Windows machine

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/contributing/Building,%20Debugging,%20and%20Testing%20on%20Windows.md

it says you should run "Restore.cmd".

When I did this I got an exception in the output from PowerShell:

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ExtractToFile" with "3" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Downloads\Microsoft\RoslynDownloadsFromGitHub\roslyn-master-32414\roslyn-master\Binaries\Tools\dotnet\additionalDeps\Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup.deps.json'."
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the path was too long. When I changed the directory containing the Roslyn download from

```
E:\Downloads\Microsoft\RoslynDownloadsFromGitHub\roslyn-master-32414\roslyn-master
```

to just

```
E:\Roslyn\32414
```

then the script ran OK.